# Can someone explain what this is in the ui component xml

Tags: magento2, xml, uicomponent

Can someone explain what ${$.$data} is doing in sales_order_grid.xml

```
 <columns name="sales_order_columns">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid.sales_order_grid.sales_order_columns.actions</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">view</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
```

Comment: I believe it's an implementation of a new feature in ecma 6 called 'template literals'. http://es6-features.org/#StringInterpolation

Answer (score 0):

This layout will dynamic load data from row from js render. When `sales_order_grid` render columns layout will get data from js and render it to browser. `$.$data.rowIndex` represent to sales_order_grid get property data and get rowIndex